# Use custom user ID without having a user

Tags: linux, user

I want to use a custom user ID and group ID on demand without changing or even having a user account with this ID.

Using Docker this can be done easily:

```
> docker run -it --rm -u 10000:10000 bash
bash-5.2$ id
uid=10000 gid=10000
bash-5.2$ whoami
whoami: unknown uid 10000
```

But how can this be done without Docker?

Comment: What issue are you trying to solve by using a custom (non-existent) user id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any tool can do that by calling the standard `setuid()` function (or `setreuid()`, etc). It only needs privileges to switch UIDs in general – typically you must be root – but there is no check of any kind for the UID's existence in the account database.

```c
int main(void) {
    setuid(1234);
}
```

(In this case, although the `docker` tool doesn't directly have privileges to setuid(), it talks to the dockerd daemon which does have such privileges.)

One such tool commonly found on Linux is `setpriv`, another is `chpst`:

```
# setpriv --reuid 1234 id
uid=1234 gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

They also allow the "real" and "effective" UIDs to be different (to simulate running a 'setuid' tool):

```
# setpriv --ruid 1234 --euid 5678 --rgid 1234 --egid 5678 --clear-groups id
uid=1234 gid=1234 euid=5678 egid=5678 groups=5678
```

The only reason this does not work with `sudo -u "#1234"` or with `runuser -u 1234` is that they *deliberately* check the account database in order to retrieve the home directory and other parameters.